# LINQ to Entities Distinct clause giving a very strange error

Tags: linq-to-entities, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6

I have a, soon to be, range of **DeviceId** values in that column, in a database of about 40k rows. I thought the following query would quite easily give me a set of distinct **DeviceId** values, but it bombs with the error below it:

```
        ctx = New DataMonitorDbContext()
        devs = ctx.DataRecords.Select(Function(r) r.DeviceId).Distinct()
```

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Int32]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.

Although currently all my device ids are 1, a SQL DISTINCT query returns 1 in an instant. This is EF to SqlCE by the way. All does not seem kosher with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .ToList() to the second statement:

```
devs = ctx.DataRecords.Select(Function(r) r.DeviceId).Distinct().ToList()
```